# Vectorizing an image like "Trace Bitmap" in Inkscape

Tags: graphics, image-processing

Lately, we had a nice question about [artistic image vectorization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8507/187) which got very nice answers. 
As [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) pointed out himself

> Since "true" vectorization performed by various specialized software is a tough problem, I suggest to consider "artistic" approaches, which produce inexact, but beautiful version of the original.

And this is true: Sophisticated bitmap tracers like the  implementation in [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) let you adjust how many color-levels, how detailed or how smooth the vectorized image should be. Following example was created from a Mathematica image with Inkscape:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Still, I wonder whether it is possible to implement a vectorizer which comes very close to the behavior of the above without re-implementing the algorithm but with the help of the many tools we have in Mathematica?**

Answer (score 27):

## Short answer

Yes, we can. With good CPU and memory resources even in a very high quality.

## Introduction

I stumbled over this issue while thinking about [this answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11339/187) where in my opinion a high quality vectorizer would be of great help. Then I read about how this is done in real applications and read the documentation to [Potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/) which is the underlying tracer of Inkscape.

At this point it was clear to me, that we can achieve this with the tools included into Mathematica. The only question was, whether it gives reasonable results.

In the following sections I explain what steps are necessary  to vectorize a **color** image in Mathematica.

## Implementation

### Segmentation

The first thing one has to understand is that color vectorization happens in multiple *scans*, which means regions of equal color will be transformed in a polygon-representation. A usual 8 bit color image with 256^3 possible colors has in the worst case a different color for each pixel.

In a vectorized image you want not only a realistic look but if possible only a few large regions to keep the number of polygons to a reasonable number. Therefore, what you have to do is to break you input image into regions with *similar* colors, with whatever definition of *similar*. Preferably, those regions should be not too small. This depends strongly on the input and cannot always be prevented.

Assume the following image

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One fast and easy way to segment this image is to use `ColorQuantize`.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5kJ2.png"];
quantized = ColorQuantize[img, 10, Dithering -> False]
```

You can specify the number of colors in the result (10 here) and later we will transform the regions of every color on after another into a vector graphic. The option `Dithering->False` is important here, otherwise the algorithm would try to minimize the quantization error by dithering which would lead to very small regions.

We could now look on the colors in the output image and would see that there are exactly 10 different rgb-values

```
cols = Union[Flatten[ImageData[quantized, "Byte"], 1]]

(* {{19, 24, 18}, {27, 36, 23}, {40, 47, 28}, {43, 49, 30}, {50,75, 37}, 
   {84, 79, 58}, {101, 139, 121}, {160, 95, 43}, {176, 153, 96}, {177, 183, 167}}
*)
```

We will use these colors later when we draw the polygons. Let's store them

```
colors = RGBColor @@ (#/255.) & /@ cols;
```

### Separating the regions

Now we want to extract all different color regions. We need a binary mask for every region. We can create this by extracting the image data and then setting all pixel to zero which are not the specified color. If we do this for all colors we get 10 different binary masks

```
data = ImageData[quantized, "Byte", DataReversed -> True];
masks = Block[{data = 
       Image[data /. {Except[cols[[#]], {_Integer ..}] :> 0, 
          cols[[#]] :> 1}]},
     Developer`ToPackedArray[
      ImageData[GaussianFilter[Opening[data, 0], 1], "Real"]]] & /@ 
   Range[Length[cols]];

Manipulate[
 Image[Reverse[masks[[i]]]],
 {i, 1, Length[cols], 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are two extra function I used which can be adjusted to further smooth the input image or to remove very small objects: `GaussianFilter` and `Opening`

### Vectorizing

The binary masks we created representing nothing more then the *regions* which should later have a special color in the final image. To plot those regions we can use `RegionPlot` if we interpolating functions from the matrices and then defining a region to have a value greater then 1/2.

The following `RegionPlot` take the number of a specific region, uses its color and interpolating function and draws a high quality polygon-graphic:

```
ipfuncs = ListInterpolation /@ masks;
{nx, ny} = ImageDimensions[img]
With[{c = colors[[#]]}, 
   RegionPlot[ipfuncs[[#]][y, x] > 0.4, {x, 1, nx}, {y, 1, ny}, 
    PlotStyle -> c, BoundaryStyle -> None, Frame -> False, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
    PlotRange -> {{1, nx}, {1, ny}}]] &[6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The final step is, to do this for all regions and combine all `Graphics` by a `Show`. Let's pack this all in a function

```
Options[TraceBitmap] = {
   TraceLevels -> 2,
   Smooth -> 1,
   RemoveSpeckles -> 1,
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   MaxRecursion -> 3
   };
TraceBitmap[img_Image, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{data, nx, ny, levels, smoothing, speckles, imageColors, 
   rgbValues, levelMasks},

  {levels, smoothing, speckles} = 
   OptionValue[{TraceLevels, Smooth, RemoveSpeckles}];
  {nx, ny} = ImageDimensions[img];
  data = ImageData[ColorQuantize[img, levels, Dithering -> False], 
    "Byte", DataReversed -> True];
  imageColors = Union[Flatten[data, 1]];
  rgbValues = RGBColor @@ (#/255.) & /@ imageColors;
  levelMasks = 
   Block[{bm = 
        Image[data /. {Except[imageColors[[#]], {_Integer ..}] :> 0, 
           imageColors[[#]] :> 1}]},
      ListInterpolation@
       Developer`ToPackedArray[
        ImageData[GaussianFilter[Opening[bm, speckles], smoothing], 
         "Real"]]] & /@ Range[levels];

  Show[RegionPlot[levelMasks[[#]][y, x] > .4, {x, 1, nx}, {y, 1, ny}, 
      PlotStyle -> rgbValues[[#]], 
      BoundaryStyle -> Directive[rgbValues[[#]]], Frame -> False, 
      AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{1, nx}, {1, ny}}, 
      PlotPoints -> OptionValue[PlotPoints], 
      MaxRecursion -> OptionValue[MaxRecursion]] & /@ Range[levels]
   ]
  ]
```

### Results

```
TraceBitmap[img, TraceLevels -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, RemoveSpeckles -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And, of course..

```
img = Rasterize[
   Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Thickness[.01]], 
   "Image", ImageSize -> 500];
TraceBitmap[img, TraceLevels -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, RemoveSpeckles -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a decent start but it still has a long way to go.  Here is the result from Vector Magic for the frog image, for comparison: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ysKck.png

Comment: I would consider the link you gave high quality. Look at the details of this here: [i.stack.imgur.com/ucOIz.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ucOIz.png) Especially how nicely the boundaries are curved and that there are no gaps between the regions. But you are right, the tracing step with `RegionPlot` is only ok, not great.

Comment: I like your version in the comment above more than the one from Vector Magic

Comment: Interesting little side note here, something has changed (at least as of MMa 11)  with `RegionPlot` and it no longer produces any output for the interpolation function. Just an FYI should anyone check here later.